# Laravel 5.7 pagination showing but not returning the correct data when changing page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

Here is my route:

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->middleware(['auth', 'auth.admin'])->group(function () {

Route::prefix('users')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@index')->name('user');
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
$users = User::with('roles', 'group')->paginate(1);

return view('admin.user.index')->with(['users' => $users]);
```

Without the pagination, this works fine and returns the 4 results I have. with the pagination the UI part of things work, it displays me 4 links in the pagination controls (1 result per page) but when clicking the link to page 2, 3 and 4 it just returns the same first item every time.

I can see it's passing the URL param in the network tab for example:

```
http://localhost:8050/admin/users?page=2
```

However, it has no effect on the result returned so I assume the issue is with my Eloquent query?

---

After some more research, the problem isn't with the pagination the issue is with the GET params.

Even when I pass the page key directly in the URL like so: http://localhost:8050/admin/users?page=2 my GET params are empty so that's why the pagination isn't working but whats blocking the GET params from getting through?

Even doing a dd($_GET) shows the GET params as being empty.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$paginate = $request->input('page');
$itemsPerPage = 10;

if(!$paginate){
   $paginate = 1;
}   

$users = User::with('roles', 'group')->skip($paginate*$itemsPerPage)->take($itemsPerPage);

return view('admin.user.index')->with(['users' => $users]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work, it still returns the first result.

Comment: I've updated my question, GET params are not being passed, they GET super global is empty.

Comment: Use skip and take for offset and limit.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

In Controller users( change with your table name)

```
$users = DB::table('users')->paginate(1);

return view('user.index', ['users' => $users]);
```

In View

```
{{ $users->links() }}
```

Comment: That's literally what I've except you have removed Eloquent and use the query builder directly instead.

Answer (score -1):

In view file you can change this:

```
{!! $users->links() !!}
```